# Overriding the FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, flipview

is it possible to override such control mathods as Items.Add() and how to do this?

I have tried to make my CustomFlipView, but stopped when realized that i don't know how to override items collection behavior

```
class CustomFlipView:FlipView
{
    CustomFlipView()
    {
        //Custom initialization
    }
}
```

The thing i'm trying to achieve is that i want to have 6 equal sized item on each flipview page.

And it seems that i need to place items into a 2*3 grid and that grid place into the FlipView.

Thats why i am trying to override Items.Add, so i could arrange items on adding.

Comment: It's probably not possible. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to customize what happens when you add an item you might look at my current answer. You could also look into using `ItemsSource` property instead of `Items` (in most cases you wouldn't want to use `Items` directly) and [data virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx#data_virtualization) in the `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into overriding these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.clearcontainerforitemoverride.aspx